# Nodejs ejs if else condition

Tags: node.js, ejs

Here i was trying for image to load, If image comes then it should show else default image. I have tried but no result

```
<% getdata.forEach((user) => { %>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">

            <div class="service-box">
                <% if ( typeof user.image == 'undefined' ) { %>
  <img src="images/logo.png" class="" width='260' height='220'>
                <% }else { %>
  <img src="<%= user['image'] %>" class="">
                    <% } %>
            </div>
        </div>
                 <% }) %>
```

Comment: So what _does_ happen? Are you sure `user.image` can't also be an empty string?

Comment: im getting images . and for some has no image instead of loading empty image i thought to load default image

Comment: So are you sure that `user.image` is really _undefined_ when there is no image, as opposed to `null` or an empty string? Try `if (! user.image) { ... }`

Comment: yaa it is working if (! user.image)  thanks @robertklep

Comment: why?  By making -1 what you want to prove I don't understand. Im new to all this staff . I thought it is good place to share my problem Is this what i get. Felling sick to join in this stackoverflow

Comment: don't take it personal, some people just downvote for no real reason (or they don't bother to explain themselves).

Comment: Encourage to new comers. Before they start anything If something come like this they will never post question again. Thanks robertklep for your reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user.image` may also be `null` or an empty string, in which case it doesn't pass your test for `undefined`.

Try this:

```
<% if (! user.image) { %>
```